# How to add templates to my DRF Model View Set

Tags: django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a SubscriberViewSet - Model View Set. I need to create an html template at frontend from Django to serve the requests and show output from the api calls of my SubscriberViewSet

The view I have is

```
class SubscriberViewSet(ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = SubscribersSerializer
  queryset = Subscriber.objects.all()
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

What I want now is to build a template view in Django to serve requests to this Subscriber View set

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When It is ModelViewSet templates View will not be shown....we need to convert it into API View and at each get/post method 
`return render_to_response()`

Comment: you can render a template in modelviewset, by using Reponse in the list()

Answer (score 2):

Djangorestframework provides a default implementation for templates which shows allowed methods and provides a way to try those methods. Just visit the endpoint from browser and at the end of url add `format=api`. If you want custom views. you can overrides those views.

Comment: could you please share more details..I tried to look but couldn't understand